# Android studio Error. Could not create service of type TransformedFileCache

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I just updated my Android studio to 2.3.3 to 3.0.1. After restart it asked me to update my gradle. After updating to gradle to version 4.1 it is now giving following error -

> Error:(7, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project
>   'Xyz'.
>
> > Could not create service of type TransformedFileCache using .createTransformedFileCache().

My build.xml is as below -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also, my project is failing on gradle sync and giving following error -

> Gradle sync failed: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

Comment: Try to **clean** and **rebuild** project.

Comment: This is actually happening while cleaning the project.

Comment: Edit and add your **build.gradle**

Comment: clean and restart ur system. That worked for me. 
But seems it is repeatedly happening after gradle upgrade.